# Filling out inserted cell with text

Tags: excel, vba

This code is running perfectly fine on inserting blank rows based on a cell value, but now I need to also fill out those new rows in range("E") saying "False". Not sure how to make this work.

```
Sub Procedure1()
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1

    a = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 8).Value
        For j = 1 To a
        
        Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i + 1).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        
    Next
    
Next

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the inner loop using `Resize`.

And you can generally avoid [Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

```
Sub Procedure1()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim a

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
        a = .Cells(i, 8).Value 'best to check this is a number before going further
        .Rows(i + 1).Resize(a).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        .Range("E" & i + 1).Resize(a).Value = "False"
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Beat me to it ...you could also use just `False` if OP wants Boolean, obviously.

Comment: @BruceWayne - just tested and it doesn't seem to make any difference, Boolean is assumed.

Comment: @SJR I'm receiving a run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error. "a" is a number

Comment: @SJR adding this to my current code helped: ```Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i + 1).Value = "False"```

Comment: Glad it worked, not sure why you needed that. What was the value of `a` when it errored?